# Creating UIButtons side by side in a loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uibutton

I am trying to create a function that displays three buttons per row for thirty rows. My code correctly creates the buttons down the page, but I need them three across.

Here is my code:

```
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < 90; index++)
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake((scrollView.frame.size.width / 2.0f) - 50.0f, 10.0f + (50.0f * (CGFloat)index), 100.0f, 30.0f);
    button.tag = index;
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %ld", ((long)index + 1)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [zoomView addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: What’s the problem you’re having?

Comment: I was not able to create a loop displaying 3 items per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, you can just use integer division and remainder on your index to adjust the frame:

```
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < 90; index++)
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake((scrollView.frame.size.width / 2.0f) - 170.0f+ (index % 3)*120.0f, 10.0f + (50.0f * (CGFloat)(index /3)), 100.0f, 30.0f);
    button.tag = index;
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %ld", ((long)index + 1)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [zoomView addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. helped me a lot. I'm from Brazil and I'm still learning to use stackoverflow correctly, I'm sorry if I did not give your answer as correct or something, I learn to little, but anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Gercil!

Comment: By the way, you did the check just right. I edited your question a bit to better reflect what you were looking for; hope I got it right.

Comment: Thanks Javy and @mackworth! Of course @mackworth, thank you! vastly improved and sorry my English a little confusing!